# CSS not responding to data-attribute set via jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, custom-data-attribute

I am setting a `data-position` attribute on document ready via jQuery on several divs. The setting definitely works. For example, calling the below code in the Chrome console is returning `'left'`.

```
$('.card-container').data('position');
```

However in the CSS the below is not doing anything.

```
[data-position='left']
```

Hard-coding `data-position="left"` in the div is working though. What am I doing wrong? Thanks for the help

Comment: Using `data` doesn't actually add the data attribute to the markup, so it won't affect css.  You should add a class instead.

Comment: $('.card-container').attr('data-position',"set your value");

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Setting a `data` attribute as you are means that it is stored in jQuery's cache (which is an object in memory), it does not get set as an attribute on the element and therefore no CSS selector will see it.

You would need to manually set the `data` attribute using `attr` for this to work:

```
$('.card-container').attr('data-position', 'left');
```

Note however, that this will see slightly reduced performance when retrieving the data value, although we're talking miliseconds.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.card-container').attr('data-position',"set your value");
```

reference **[attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)**

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's [`data()` method](http://api.jquery.com/data/) doesn't actually change the attribute. In order to change the attribute on the element itself you'll have to use [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/):

```
$('.card-container').attr('data-position', 'value');
```

Comment: This does NOT change the 'data-position' attribute, but adds another attribute called 'position'

Comment: @adrenalin that's a good point! I'm clearly too tired to answer questions accurately today...